# Why is sending mail from PHP from my Vagrant box so slow?

Tags: php, email, sendmail, vagrant

I setup a Vagrant Box (precice64) with PHP5.3 and try to send a mail with it, but it's real slow. I have a simple script like:

```
$ok = mail('me@domain.com', 'test', 'test');
var_dump($ok);
```

And execute it on the command line (or browser, makes no difference):

```
$ php mail.php
```

The mail gets sent, but the script takes like 30 seconds to a minute to execute! Anyone know what might be causing this delay?

Comment: Have you tried sending mail from your vagrant box using sendmail to compare the time?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mail%28%29+is+taking+long+time+to+send

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by following Glavić's link.

I edited `/etc/hosts` to include the hostname of my Vagrant Box (precise64):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost myhostname precise64
```

And added the folowing line to `/etc/mail/sendmail.conf`:

```
HostsFile=/etc/hosts
```

Now it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

add this entry to your hosts file:
127.0.1.1 fullyQualifiedHostname